# Dependency Property in User Control works only on the first instance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have several custom user controls in a window. They appear dynamically, like workspaces. 
I need to add a dependency property on an itemscontrol to trigger a scrolldown when an item is being added to the bound observable collection to my itemscontrol, like so: 
(usercontrol)

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"  View:ItemsControlBehavior.ScrollOnNewItem="True">    
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
</ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And the code of my dependency property :

```
    public class ItemsControlBehavior
    {
        static readonly Dictionary<ItemsControl, Capture> Associations =
            new Dictionary<ItemsControl, Capture>();

    public static bool GetScrollOnNewItem(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ScrollOnNewItemProperty);
    }

    public static void SetScrollOnNewItem(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ScrollOnNewItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollOnNewItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ScrollOnNewItem",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(ItemsControl),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnScrollOnNewItemChanged));

    public static void OnScrollOnNewItemChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mycontrol = d as ItemsControl;
        if (mycontrol == null) return;
        bool newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
        if (newValue)
        {
            mycontrol.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyControl_Loaded);
            mycontrol.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyControl_Unloaded);
        }
        else
        {
            mycontrol.Loaded -= MyControl_Loaded;
            mycontrol.Unloaded -= MyControl_Unloaded;
            if (Associations.ContainsKey(mycontrol))
                Associations[mycontrol].Dispose();
        }
    }

    static void MyControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mycontrol = (ItemsControl)sender;
        Associations[mycontrol].Dispose();
        mycontrol.Unloaded -= MyControl_Unloaded;
    }

    static void MyControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mycontrol = (ItemsControl)sender;
        var incc = mycontrol.Items as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (incc == null) return;
        mycontrol.Loaded -= MyControl_Loaded;
        Associations[mycontrol] = new Capture(mycontrol);
    }

    class Capture : IDisposable
    {
        public ItemsControl mycontrol{ get; set; }
        public INotifyCollectionChanged incc { get; set; }

        public Capture(ItemsControl mycontrol)
        {
            this.mycontrol = mycontrol;
            incc = mycontrol.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            incc.CollectionChanged +=incc_CollectionChanged;
        }

        void incc_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                  ScrollViewer sv = mycontrol.Parent as ScrollViewer;
                sv.ScrollToBottom();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            incc.CollectionChanged -= incc_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

During the first instantiation of my user control, it works like a charm.
But when another user control of the same type is dynamically instantiated, the DependencyProperty is never attached anymore to my scrollviewer. Only the first instance will work correctly. 
I know that dependency properties are static, but does that mean they can't work at the same time on several user control of the same type added to the window?

Update 02/03 : Here's how I set the viewmodel to the view (not programmatically) :

```
      <ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:testDp.ViewModel" 
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:testDp.View">


  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChatTabViewModel}">
<View:ChatTabView />
  </DataTemplate>        
  </ResourceDictionary>
```

even with x:shared = false in the datatemplate tag, it won't work.
But if I set the datacontext in a classic way like usercontrol.datacontext = new viewmodel(), it definitely work. But it's recommended to have a "shared" view, so how do we make dependency properties work with this "xaml" way of setting datacontext ?

Comment: your second typeof in the DependencyProperty creation should be the type of the owner class, but you supplied ItemsControl, change that to ItemsControlBehavior. But i don't think this is causing your problem.

Comment: my bad... thank you. Unfortunately yes, the problem remains...

Comment: I can see two static functions acting as get/set. Why are you not using a property wrapper for the dependencyproperty  as per the convention?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I couldn't reproduce your problem.

I started Visual C# 2010 Express,  created a new 'WPF Application', added your XAML to a `UserControl` that I imaginatively titled `UserControl1`, and added your `ItemsControlBehavior` class.  I then modified the MainWindow that VC# created for me as follows:

MainWindow.xaml (contents of `<Window>` element only):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button Content="Add user control" Click="ButtonAddUserControl_Click" />
    <Button Content="Add message" Click="ButtonAddMessage_Click" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="sp" Height="300" />
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void ButtonAddUserControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Children.Add(new UserControl1());
    }

    private void ButtonAddMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Messages.Add((Messages.Count + 1).ToString());
    }
}
```

I made no modifications to the XAML in your UserControl, nor to your `ItemsControlBehavior` class.

I found that no matter how many user controls were added, their ScrollViewers all scrolled down to the bottom when I clicked the 'Add message' button.

If you're only seeing the scroll-to-the-bottom behaviour on one of your user controls, then there must be something that you're not telling us.

Comment: Thank you for your attempts !
I'm gonna do the same with a very simple test project like you and see, if things work on it, what's different in my project and I'll keep this post updated. tks

Comment: Ok it works simply like that. I don't know if it has something to do with it but in my real project I don't set programmatically View.DataContext = ViewModel, but I put it in a resources dictionnary like that : <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserControlViewModel}"> <View:UserControl1 /> </DataTemplate> maybe it creates only one view for several viewmodel ? separating instances when forced only ?

Comment: @Anna Yes, if you create it in xaml, it will be create once and reused. There is a flag you can use to NOT share it using x:Shared="false" on your resource.

Comment: I'm trying to use Shared false right now, but it says resource dictionary must be compiled to use this. I try to set compile action in the dictionary's file's properties but it won't accept the syntax of my dictionary anymore...

Comment: Ok now I truly believe I should add x:Shared="false" like it's said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900301/why-the-view-constructor-is-not-called-every-time-i-create-a-new-viewmodel But it says : "resource dictionary must be compiled" and I can't find a workaround...

Comment: I tried to set that  : 
  <DataTemplate x:Shared="false" DataType="{x:Type vm:ChatTabViewModel}">
    <View:ChatTabView />
  </DataTemplate>
but it doesn't change anything :(